# NSLogger for Ad Hoc testing

Tags: ios

I am looking for a log framework which can show log on my mac when I am running app on my device as ad Hoc distribution.

I have come across NSLogger.

It is working good in simulator but if I run on device (from xcode or from net) it is not working.

Not working means mac Desktop Viewer application is not launching as it launch when I run on simulator.

How can I integrate NSLogger so that I can get log from device to my MAC?

Is there any other framework which provide me this kind of logging?

Thanks.

Comment: TestFlight offers something very similar.

Comment: @Thilo ok let me check

Comment: NSLogger desktop viewer never automatically launches (I don't know what makes you think that). Make sure you have the viewer open when your app on device start. By default, NSLogger client uses Bonjour to find the desktop viewer. Make sure firewall configuration on your Mac allows Bonjour to go through.

There's no reason you can't get this working from a device.

Comment: @fpillet hi. Sorry for late reply. Have you used NSLogger? I like to learn how to use it. DO u have any link for this?

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps I took to get NSLogger to work.  For the desktop viewer:

- download the [desktop viewer binary](https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger/releases/download/v1.5/NSLogger-Desktop.Viewer.1.5.zip) or
- follow desktop viewer xcode instructions: [part one](https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger/wiki/Building-the-NSLogger-viewer) and [part two](https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger/tree/master/Desktop%20Viewer)
- run the desktop viewer
- goto `NSLogger->Preferences->Network`
- check `Publish Bonjour service for automatic discovery on local network`
- type `NSLogger` in the `Bonjour service name` text box
- goto `NSLogger->Window->Show Logger Status` and you should see a status window that displays this:

  - Bonjour (Ready to accept connections)
  - Bonjour SSL (Ready to accept connections)
  - TCP/IP Port 50000 (Unavailable)
- NOTE: At this point you WILL NOT see the desktop viewer output window... that window only appear when an NSLogger client correctly connects to the desktop viewer.

For the iOS client:

- make sure that your iOS device is on the same local network as the computer running the desktop viewer
- install the app `Discovery` which allows you to browse the Bonjour networks
- run `Discovery` and browse the local Bonjour network, you should see two entries published by NSLogger desktop viewer:

  - `_nsloggger._tcp.`
  - `_nslogger-ssl._tcp.`
- integrate the NSLogger client with your iOS application by following these [instructions](https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger)
- when you are done integrating your project will look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ne9Mu.png) (my project is named iosTapDetectorDemo)
- add `#import <NSLogger/NSLogger.h>` statements where needed (for me this was in include files included by method files that made NSLogger method calls)
- replace all `NSLog` method calls with `LoggerCompat` method calls
- add the following code to your main program:

  ```
  LoggerSetOptions(LoggerGetDefaultLogger(), kLoggerOption_BrowseBonjour|kLoggerOption_BufferLogsUntilConnection);
  LoggerSetupBonjour(LoggerGetDefaultLogger(), CFSTR("_nslogger._tcp"), CFSTR("NSLogger"));
  LoggerStart(LoggerGetDefaultLogger());
  ```
- run your iOS application, a logger output window should appear on the desktop viewer and your `LoggerCompat` method calls should display text in the viewer